# Excel 365 - Y-axis range modification of line chart

Tags: excel

Want to set min/max scale for an axis range in Excel?

My data ranges from 1.06 - 1.39 but the line chart starts at 0 - so loads of white space.

I've had a look at the formatting options but don't see anything there. Does it need to be done via VBA?

Answer (score 0):

So, set your axis using the Format axis options like so:

[image]

Comment: Ah. Thanks very much for that. My menu is different and I found the Vertical (Value) Axis menu and was able to edit the bounds from there.